# How to block signals until all other signals are processed?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm working on a Qt widget that provides a grid of plots (each one is a QWidget). I want to synchronize the "keepAspectRatio" policy on all my plots.

Each individual plot will emit a `sigKeepAspectRatioChanged` signal if I call its `setKeepDataAspectRatio(bool)` method, that broadcasts the policy (`True` or `False`) and its `(row, column)` coordinate in the grid.

My composite widget listens to all its plots, and when one of them changes it's aspect ratio policy (click on a tool button), it needs to propagate it to all other plots.

This is what I tried, but it causes an infinite number of `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp` errors:

```
    def _onKeepAspectRatioChanged(self, isKeepAspectRatio, row, col):
       """If any plot changes its keepAspectRatio policy,
        apply it to all other plots."""
        print("received sigKeepAspectRatioChanged from plot %d, %d" % (row, col))
        self.blockSignals(True)
        for r, c in self._plots:
            if not (r, c) == (row, col):
                self._plots[(r, c)].plot.setKeepDataAspectRatio(isKeepAspectRatio)
        qt.QApplication.instance().processEvents()
        self.blockSignals(False)
```

Any ideas on how to do this properly?

BTW, the reference to each individual plot is kept in a dictionary (`self. _plots`), and the dict key is the `(r, c)` coordinate tuple.

Comment: What you need to do is use `blockSignals` on the widgets that are actually emitting the signals (i.e. `self._plots[(r, c)]`). There's no point calling it on `self`, because by then it's too late.

Answer (score 2):

What you really care for is that the method is not re-entered. The signals and slots are just a conduit for it happening. Thus: protect the relevant methods from recursion. It's more than an order of magnitude more efficient than breaking- and restoring signal-slot connections. Essentially:

```
def _method(self, ...):
  if self.in_method:
    return
  try:
    self.in_method = True
    ...
  finally:
    self.in_method = False
```

This could be of course wrapped in a decorator:

```
@norecursion
def _onKeepAspectRatioChanged(self, isKeepAspectRatio, row, col):
  ...
```

And the decorator from [this blog post](http://blog.lost-theory.org/post/decorator-for-preventing-recursion/):

```
def norecursion(default=None):
  '''Prevents recursion into the wrapped function.'''
  def entangle(f):
    def inner(*args, **kwds):
      if not hasattr(f, 'callcount'):
        f.callcount = 0
      if f.callcount >= 1:
        return default
      else:
        f.callcount += 1
        x = f(*args, **kwds)
        f.callcount -= 1
        return x
    return inner
  return entangle
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution, but it may not be the most efficient one: I disconnect all the individual signals, then reconnect after setting all the policies.

```
def _onKeepAspectRatioChanged(self, isKeepAspectRatio, row, col):
    with self._disconnectAllAspectRatioSignals():
        for r, c in self._plots:
            self._plots[(r, c)].plot.setKeepDataAspectRatio(isKeepAspectRatio)

@contextlib.contextmanager
def _disconnectAllAspectRatioSignals(self):
    for r, c in self._plots:
        self._plots[(r, c)].sigKeepAspectRatioChanged.disconnect(
            self._onKeepAspectRatioChanged)
    yield
    for r, c in self._plots:
        self._plots[(r, c)].sigKeepAspectRatioChanged.connect(
            self._onKeepAspectRatioChanged)
```